# Informatica Powercenter String to Decimal Conversion

Tags: decimal, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to load data from flat file to oracle table.

The flat file has data as string and the value is **123412345678.123457689123**
When converting to decimal , the value is becoming as **123412345678.123000000000**

The target column is number (38,12).
In the mapping I have defined the data type as decimal (38,12) while converting to decimal.

Any inputs?

Comment: I would recommend, read as string from file and then use informatica `TO_DECIMAL( IN_col, 12 )` to convert to decimal(38,12). Sometime implicit conversion doesnt work/misbehaves. But informatica can handle - Precision 1 to 28 digits, scale 0 to 28

Comment: @KoushikRoy : doing the same, not working. even tried selecting high precision in session properties.

Comment: when you read as string - is it read properly?

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'Enable High Precision' checked? Please read the following [guide](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/advanced-workflow-guide/high-precision-data/decimal.html).

Briefly: without the high precision enabled, the data is converted to Double and precision loss occures. If high precision is enabled, this will work up to 28 digits. With larger values it will still happen.

The only way to make sure you have this always working right is to process this as string.